# outofmemoryerror in android

Tags: android

I have one running some methods  in doInBackground in AsyncTask ,which is calling webservices and inserting number of records  into the database , at the same user click on other screen then outOfmemoryError is coming I want to stop the background thread temporarily till the screen loads and then thread has to resume from it stopped such that the memory will release. can anybody tell me how to achieve this. 
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: There are two periods in that question.

Comment: i can't undersatand what you are asking

Comment: I think You should use Service for this.

Comment: thanks for your response Nitin,here  the records should be inserted without this memory issue

Answer (score 0):

The Asynctask can be executed only once (an exception will be thrown if a second execution is attempted.).. so to pause and resume .. i think you should use a backgroundthread instead...

Answer (score 0):

```
    //decleration
ProgressDialog dialog;

//onCreate
dialog = new ProgressDialog(ActivityName.this);

public class BackGroundTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            //perform background task

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();
            dialog.setMessage("Please wait.....");
            dialog.setIndeterminate(true);
            dialog.setCancelable(false);
            dialog.show();

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String sResponse) {

                if (dialog.isShowing())
                         {
                    dialog.dismiss();

                      }

    }
```